# what do these symbolic strings mean: %02d %01d?

Tags: java, printf

I'm looking at a code line similar to:

```
sprintf(buffer,"%02d:%02d:%02d",hour,minute,second);
```

I think the symbolic strings refer to the number of numeric characters displayed per hour, minute etc - or something like that, I am not entirely certain.

Normally I can figure this sort of thing out but I have been unable to find any useful reference searching "%02d %01d" on google. Anyone able to shed some light on this for me?

Comment: It is also present in C++, and many other C-like languages.

Comment: Adding to AlexanderMP comment (to help search engines) it also is used the same way in R the sprintf {base} function is a wrapper for the C function.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

the same rules should apply to Java.

in your case it means output of integer values in 2 or more digits, the first being zero if number less than or equal to 9

Answer (score 75):

Instead of Googling for `%02d` you should have been searching for `sprintf()` function.

`%02d` means "format the integer with 2 digits, left padding it with zeroes", so:

```
Format  Data   Result
%02d    1      01
%02d    11     11
```

Comment: following up on the examples given, `format: %02d, data: 111, result: 111`. The format will ensure at least 2 decimal digits, with a leading zeros if there are less decimal digits, but preserving the existing ones if there are more.

Answer (score 38):

They are formatting `String`. The Java specific syntax is given in [`java.util.Formatter`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

The general syntax is as follows:

```
   %[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion
```

`%02d` performs decimal integer conversion `d`, formatted with zero padding (`0` flag), with width `2`. Thus, an `int` argument whose value is say `7`, will be formatted into `"07"` as a `String`.

You may also see this formatting string in e.g. [`String.format`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29).

---

### Commonly used formats

These are just some commonly used formats and doesn't cover the syntax exhaustively.

#### Zero padding for numbers

```
System.out.printf("Agent %03d to the rescue!", 7);
// Agent 007 to the rescue!
```

#### Width for justification

You can use the `-` flag for left justification; otherwise it'll be right justification.

```
for (Map.Entry<Object,Object> prop : System.getProperties().entrySet()) {
    System.out.printf("%-30s : %50s%n", prop.getKey(), prop.getValue());
}
```

This prints something like:

```
java.version                   :                                 1.6.0_07
java.vm.name                   :               Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
java.vm.vendor                 :                    Sun Microsystems Inc.
java.vm.specification.name     :       Java Virtual Machine Specification
java.runtime.name              :          Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
java.vendor.url                :                     http://java.sun.com/
```

For more powerful message formatting, you can use [`java.text.MessageFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html). `%n` is the newline conversion (see below).

#### Hexadecimal conversion

```
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(255));
// ff

System.out.printf("%d is %<08X", 255);
// 255 is 000000FF
```

Note that this also uses the `<` relative indexing (see below).

#### Floating point formatting

```
System.out.printf("%+,010.2f%n", 1234.567);
System.out.printf("%+,010.2f%n", -66.6666);
// +01,234.57
// -000066.67
```

For more powerful floating point formatting, use [`DecimalFormat`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.6.0/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) instead.

#### `%n` for platform-specific line separator

```
System.out.printf("%s,%n%s%n", "Hello", "World");
// Hello,
// World
```

#### `%%` for an actual `%`-sign

```
System.out.printf("It's %s%% guaranteed!", 99.99);
// It's 99.99% guaranteed!
```

Note that the `double` literal `99.99` is autoboxed to `Double`, on which a string conversion using `toString()` is defined.

#### `n$` for explicit argument indexing

```
System.out.printf("%1$s! %1$s %2$s! %1$s %2$s %3$s!",
    "Du", "hast", "mich"
);
// Du! Du hast! Du hast mich!
```

#### `<` for relative indexing

```
System.out.format("%s?! %<S?!?!?", "Who's your daddy");
// Who's your daddy?! WHO'S YOUR DADDY?!?!?
```

---

#### Related questions

- [Why is String’s format(Object… args) defined as a static method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792259/why-is-strings-formatobject-args-defined-as-a-static-method)
- [escaping formatting characters in java String.format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201312/escaping-formatting-characters-in-java-string-format)
- [Is it better practice to use String.format over string Concatenation in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925423/is-it-better-practice-to-use-string-format-over-string-concatenation-in-java)
- [Should I use Java’s String.format() if performance is important?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513600/should-i-use-javas-string-format-if-performance-is-important)
- [Understanding the $ in Java’s format strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915074/understanding-the-in-javas-format-strings)
- [java decimal String format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433958/java-decimal-string-format)
- [difference between system.out.printf and String.format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080112/difference-between-system-out-printf-and-string-format)
- [What classes do you use to make string templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948291/what-classes-do-you-use-to-make-string-templates) -- `MessageFormat` with example

Answer (score 1):

**%** is a special character you put in format strings, for example in C language printf and scanf (and family), that basically says *"this is a placeholder for something else, not to be printed/read literally."*

> For example, a `(%02d)` in a format string for printf is a placeholder for an integer variable that will be printed in decimal  `(%02d)`  and padded to at least two digits, with zeros if necessary.
>
> > The actual integer is supplied by you in an an argument to the function, e.g. `printf("%02d",5);`
> > would print `05` on screen, `(%01d)` also works similarly

Same hold for Java and other languages too :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Alexander refers to complete docs...

Your simple example from the question simply prints out these values with 2 digits - appending leading 0 if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf#printf_format_placeholders

The article is about the *class* of printf functions, in several languages, from the 50s to this day.