# String.format() to fill a string?

Tags: java

I need to fill a String to a certain length with dashes, like:

```
cow-----8
cow-----9
cow----10
...
cow---100
```

the total length of the string needs to be 9. The prefix "cow" is constant. I'm iterating up to an input number. I can do this in an ugly way:

```
String str = "cow";
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    if (i < 10) {
        str += "-----";
    } 
    else if (i < 100) {
        str += "----";
    }
    else if (i < 1000) {
        str += "---";
    }
    else if (i < 10000) {
        str += "--";
    }
    str += i;
}
```

can I do the same thing more cleanly with string format?

Thanks

Comment: Sidenote: For appending to `Strings` in a loop like you do in your example, you may want to use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Agreed am using it in my local code just did this for brevity (not that it really saved anything now that I looked at it)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
    int[] nums = { 1, 12, 123, 1234, 12345, 123456 };
    for (int num : nums) {
        System.out.println("cow" + String.format("%6d", num).replace(' ', '-'));
    }
```

This prints:

```
cow-----1
cow----12
cow---123
cow--1234
cow-12345
cow123456
```

The key expression is this:

```
String.format("%6d", num).replace(' ', '-')
```

This uses [`String.format`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29), digit conversion, width 6 right justified padding with spaces. We then [`replace`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) each space (if any) with dash.

Optionally, since the prefix doesn't contain any space in this particular case, you can bring the cow in:

```
String.format("cow%6d", num).replace(' ', '-')
```

#### See also

- [`java.util.Formatter`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) - for full formatting syntax

Comment: Great, one question - can I supply the format string (the first parameter to format()) as a variable? I know it should be %6d, but can I probably want to compute the value '6', in case I want total length to be 10 or 20 etc. Can I just do String str = "%%" + (fixedlen - "cow".length()) + "d", and supply that as the first param?

Comment: @user246114: I think you want `String fmt = "%" + w + "d";` (one `%` only), or possibly `String fmt = String.format("%%%dd", w);`, and then `String.format(fmt, num)`.

Comment: CORRECTION: I meant _decimal_ conversion, not _digit_ conversion. Will correct soon.

Comment: @user246114: I'm not sure exactly what you're doing, but you may want to look at the width justification formatting example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377688/what-do-these-symbolic-strings-mean-02d-01d/3377719#3377719 ; specifically you can combine left and right justification.