# How to format a string n number of times with a specified character, and then append it to another string?

Tags: java, string, formatting, string-formatting, string-utils

As the title says, given a string, I would like to pad it (append) with n number of x character. Please see the below code. Is it possible to do that all in one String.format?

The commented line shows how to append n number of spaces; I would like to do the exact same thing with a custom character.

```
int paddingLength = (int) args.get(0); 
String paddingItem = (String) args.get(1); 

String temp = ((String) row.get(fieldName));


//temp = String.format("%-" + n + "s", s); 

temp = String.format("%-" + paddingLength + "paddingItem", paddingItem + "temp", temp);
```

Example:

```
paddingLength: 5
paddingItem: "_"
temp = "test"

result: "test_____"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450758/string-format-to-fill-a-string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple way to repeat a String in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235179/simple-way-to-repeat-a-string-in-java)

Comment: @kai Hi, thanks for the response. Unfortunately that has to do with replacing characters - I want to append characters where there were no characters before.

Comment: @uneq95 Not to do with replacing characters. Please see the example I just edited with

Comment: you want instead the of the space in the example underscores -> replace the spaces with underscores.

Comment: What is args here? Whatever it is, are you sure you can cast one member to an int and another to a String?

Comment: String.format("%-" + n + "s", s).replace(' ','_');

Comment: Use `paddingItem.repeat(paddingLength)` *(Java 11+)*

Comment: When you set the padding length as 5, then for the string "test", it will append only 1 space character, not 5, to the end of "test".

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using StringBuilder.
Example.

```
int n = 5;
char x = '_';
String temp = "test";
StringBuilder paddedWord = new StringBuilder(temp);
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    paddedWord.append(x);
```

Just remember to cast your StringBuilder back to a String if you are using it elsewhere `.toString()`